# Get the button text of pushed button within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons in a span

```
<span class="somespan">
<button type="button">left</button>
<button type="button">right</button>
</span>
```

I have set up an `.on` event to trigger when one is activated.

```
$('.somespan').on("mousedown tap", function() {
direction = ($(this).text());
})
```

This produces the result `leftright` as it provides the button text for all buttons. How do I only get the button text for the clicked button?

Comment: attatch the listener to the buttons ;)

Comment: So you want title of particular clicked button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've attached the event to the `span`. For `this` to refer to the `button` elements, you need to attach the event to that element instead. Try this:

```js
$('.somespan button').on("mousedown tap", function() {
  direction = $(this).text();
  console.log(direction);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="somespan">
  <button type="button">left</button>
  <button type="button">right</button>
</span>
```

Alternatively, if you *have* to select the `span`, then you can find the clicked element by using `event.target` instead of `this`. Note the `e` in the handler function parameters.

```js
$('.somespan').on("mousedown tap", function(e) {
  direction = $(e.target).text();
  console.log(direction);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="somespan">
  <button type="button">left</button>
  <button type="button">right</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attatch the listener to the buttons :)

```
$('button').on("mousedown tap", function() {
    direction = ($(this).text());
})
```

or in the span

```
$('.somespan').on("mousedown tap","button", function() {
    direction = ($(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
$('.somespan button').on("mousedown tap", function() {
direction = ($(this).text());
})
```

In your case, you are adding the mousedown event to the span instead of the button